# Renaming Custom Modules in Apostrophe

Tags: apostrophe-cms

We are refactoring our custom modules to include a namespace attribute for the project. We’ve made all of the changes in code but it appears that references to the names of the modules rather than an ID is used to identify the module type in mongo. Looking at the aposDocs collection, it is unclear to me where those references exist. Can you point me in the right direction?

Thanks!
Ken

Answer (score 0):

The `type` property in mongodb comes from the `name` option that was set for the module. This is generally singular, because it is identifying one instance. For instance, when extending `apostrophe-pieces` to create a module called `places`, you will typically set the `name` option to `place`.

I'm not sure what your precise goal is here, but it is not uncommon for us to give a project a unique two-letter prefix, naming modules things like `as-places` and setting name options to things like `as-place`.

Pages, of course, also have a `type` property in MongoDB. These are defined in `apostrophe-pages`, in the `types` option.

If I haven't understood your goal clearly please clarify and we can continue the conversation in comments.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Tom, I think I'm running into a similar issue. I've refactored a few modules. For instance I want to rename a module from idea-oveview to be named resource-overview, but I want old sites that have configured an idea-overview to stil be compatible. I can't find a good way to do this. Maybe symlink? Or is it possible to load in old widget name but refer it to the new directory. Or better to write a script to update old sites? I can't find it in the docs.

Comment: You will have to write a migration, using `apos.migrations.eachWidget` in your migration code. See: https://docs.apostrophecms.org/apostrophe/reference/modules/apostrophe-migrations